# JAR not opening even with manifest

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I'm trying to run the following statement on the terminal

```
java -jar /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys\ sysa_a/sys-client/out/artifacts/sys_client_jar/sys-client.jar
```

However, I'm always met with the following:

```
no main manifest attribute, in Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys\ sysa_a/sys-client/out/artifacts/sys_client_jar/sys-client.jar
```

However, I have the manifest file located here:

```
/Users/santoki/Documents/workspace/sys\ client_a/sys-client/src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

The manifest has the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sysClient.data.gui.sysClient
```

Can anyone help lead me to the right direction?

---

On the terminal:

```
jar tvf  /Users/bigbitecode/Documents/workspace/sys\ client_a/sys-client/out/artifacts/sys_client_jar/sys-client.jar
     0 Mon Jun 17 15:27:22 PDT 2013 META-INF/
   112 Mon Jun 17 15:27:22 PDT 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: Your manifest must be in the jar for this to work, it is no use if it is in a separate file. Is it packaged in the jar? (try `jar tf thejar|grep MANIFEST`)

Comment: i tried running the grep and it found : META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: OK well, the next thing is to check whether your main class is really what you think it is (name and package); do tell, there _is_ a `main()`, right?

Comment: yes, the main method is there. I've tried creating the jar automatically with intelliJ, and manually, but the results have always been the same...

Comment: @bigbitecode - do a `jar tvf sys-client.jar` and post the listing.

Comment: 0 Mon Jun 17 15:27:22 PDT 2013 META-INF/
112 Mon Jun 17 15:27:22 PDT 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: the ... whole listing.

Comment: I just edited my main post of what happens when I type "jar tvf {...}sys-client.jar

Comment: So ... see? There's nothing *but* the manifest in your jar file. That ... would be a problem ;)

Comment: embarrassing... Thanks guys. haha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **Main-Class: Fully Qualified ClassName** here in your MANIFEST.MF

This acts as a entry point to the application. It simple means that above class has main method with signature `public static void main(String a[])`

You can refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Yes, I do have an entry point. It's Main-Class: sysClient.data.gui.sysClient